# How do you store some rust futures in a list and retrieve them all?

Tags: rust, async-await

Note: I am using `nightly` so that I can use `async` traits with static dispatch (as opposed to `async-traits` crate). Also, this code is contrived so I boil down to the simplest example, so there could be some syntax or other issues.

I have a trait:

```
pub trait MakesWidgets {
  async fn make_widget(&self) -> Result<Widget, String>;
}
```

And I have an implementation:

```
impl MakesWidgets for DefaultWidgetMaker {
  async fn make_widget(&self) -> Result<Widget, String> {
    self.make_widget_internal().await
  }
}
```

Now I want to define a method on `DefaultWidgetMaker`:

```
impl DefaultWidgetMaker {
  pub async fn make_widgets(&self, requests: Vec<bool>) -> Vec<Result<Widget, String>> {
    let n = requests.len();
    let mut responses = Vec::with_capacity(n);
    for _ in 0..n { responses.push(None); }
    let mut pending = Vec::with_capacity(n);
    for _ in 0..n { pending.push(None); }
    for (i, should_block) in requests.iter().enumerate() {
      let future = self.make_widget();
      if should_block {
        responses[i] = Some(future.await);
      } else {
        pending[i] = Some(future);
      }
    }
    for (i, maybe_future) in pending.iter().enumerate() {
      if let Some(ref mut future) = maybe_future {
        responses[i] = Some(future.await);
      }
    }
    responses.map(|x| x.unwrap())
  }
}
```

This results in the error:

```
#0 4.372 error[E0277]: `impl futures_util::Future<Output = std::result::Result<Widget, std::string::String>>` cannot be unpinned
#0 4.372   --> src/xxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx.rs:65:38
#0 4.372    |
#0 4.372 65 |                 let response = future.await;
#0 4.372    |                                      ^^^^^^
#0 4.372    |                                      |
#0 4.372    |                                      the trait `Unpin` is not implemented for `impl futures_util::Future<Output = std::result::Result<Widget, std::string::String>>`
#0 4.372    |                                      help: remove the `.await`
#0 4.372    |
#0 4.372    = note: consider using `Box::pin`
#0 4.372    = note: required for `&mut impl futures_util::Future<Output = std::result::Result<Widget, std::string::String>>` to implement `futures_util::Future`
#0 4.372    = note: required for `&mut impl futures_util::Future<Output = std::result::Result<Widget, std::string::String>>` to implement `std::future::IntoFuture`
```

Comment: Please construct a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Future` doesn't implement `Unpin`, because it [might contain pointers, which are unsafe to move](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/04_pinning/01_chapter.html). In this specific case, you can resolve the error by not wrapping your `Future`s in `Option`s (thereby not having to move them, when unwrapping) like so:

```rust
async fn do_something() -> i32 {
    1
}

async fn do_stuff(requests: Vec<bool>) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut pending = vec![];
    let mut resolved = vec![0; requests.len()];
    
    for (i, should_block) in requests.into_iter().enumerate() {
        let future = do_something();
        if should_block {
            resolved[i] = future.await;
        } else {
            // Save the index for later reference
            pending.push((i, future));
        }
    }

    // Use the stored index to insert the future's result at
    // a specific position
    for (i, future) in pending {
        resolved[i] = future.await;
    }

    resolved
}
```

This works well with types that are inexpensive to initialize, but I assume you don't want to create an array of default widgets just to replace them later on (hence the use of `Option`). In this case, you could do something similar to your original example:

```rust
async fn do_stuff_option(requests: Vec<bool>) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut pending = vec![];
    let mut resolved = vec![None; requests.len()];
    
    for (i, should_block) in requests.into_iter().enumerate() {
        let future = do_something();
        if should_block {
            resolved[i] = Some(future.await);
        } else {
            // Save the index for later reference
            pending.push((i, future));
        }
    }

    // Use the stored index to insert the future's result at
    // a specific position
    for (i, future) in pending {
        resolved[i] = Some(future.await);
    }

    resolved
        .into_iter()
        .map(|x| x.unwrap())
        .collect()
}
```

To keep it as simple as possible, I omitted the trait/impl blocks and just used functions. It works just as well with async traits ([Rust playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c9ac7f2e020e64d000905bfe2bbb5705)). For a more detailed explainaition of pinning, check out [this Cloudflare blog post](https://blog.cloudflare.com/pin-and-unpin-in-rust/) or [the docs on `std::pin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/pin/index.html).

Comment: Thank you... I have some questions though.

Comment: Whoops... so in my example, I had initialized an array of `None`s with type `Option<crazy Future type>` and in yours, your `pending` was of type `(usize, crazy Future type)`. In my example, I use `if let Some(x) = maybe_future` to attempt to get a reference to the future from the array of options, and in yours, you know that the tuples in `pending` will definitely contain tuples of `usize` and the future type.

Comment: I keep hitting enter and meaning to insert a line break. So what gives the compiler trouble about the pattern match on `if let Some(x) = maybe_future` and how does it relate to `Pin` and `Unpin`? My original intuition was that `Pin`/`Unpin` had to do with making sure that a future runs on a specific core. IE if in my main thread I spawn the future by calling the async function, and that future runs on some core, then when I am iterating over `pending` and trying to use `if let` there is some problem with reading the result of the future on a maybe different core... is that kind of the gist?